JMeter 5.6.2 timing out while communicating to InfluxDB 2.7.7 Container instance
I got below error when implemented "jmeter-influxdb2-listener-plugin"
2024-08-16 13:47:46,389 ERROR i.g.m.i.v.InfluxDatabaseBackendListenerClient: Error has occurred, batch with size 4 was not imported, see the details --> Connect timed out
**InfluxDb2.7.7 Container instance log:-**

2024-08-16 13:54:50 ts=2024-08-16T08:24:50.186563Z lvl=error msg="Unable to write gathered points" log_id=0r2ZIpSl000 service=scraper scraper-name="new target" error="database not found: 0a1647670a6ae644

I expect JMeter 5.6.2 to send all the metrics of the test run to InfluxDB measurement 'jmeter' but backend listener i used is skippng the capturing of results and sending them to InfluxDB.
Note:- URL used is http://ContainerIP:8086


database not found: 0a1647670a6ae644

have you created the database in InfluxDB beforehand? JMeter won't do this for you. Check out JMeter + Grafana: How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter

If you want to process with InfluxDB v2 you will need to create an API token and bucket
and the URL to use would be something like:
http://ContainerIP:9002/api/v2/write?org=your-organization-here&bucket=your-bucket-here

and additionally you will need to provide influxdbToken parameter

I added influxdbToken parameter and also the bucket name to the Backend listener. Please refer to the screenshot attached to this question.


Open the InfluxDB UI, http://ContainerIP:8086
Go to the Load Data
Click on the + Create Bucket
Create a bucket with a proper name which you have defined in the Jmeter scenario

